# Cannot find the tailwindcss executable for x86_64-darwin-21

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Add bin/dev to start foreman
create  bin/dev
Compile initial Tailwind build
run  rails tailwindcss:build from "."
ERROR: Cannot find the tailwindcss executable for x86_64-darwin-21 in /Users/khan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/tailwindcss-rails-2.0.2/exe
If you're using bundler, please make sure you're on the latest bundler version:

gem install bundler
bundle update --bundler

Then make sure your lock file includes this platform by running:

bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-darwin-21
bundle install

See `bundle lock --help` output for details.

Answer (score 16):

1. Try add platform as the tips:

```
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-darwin-21
bundle install
```

2. Try unset `force_ruby_platform`

```
bundle config unset force_ruby_platform
# or
bundle config set --local force_ruby_platform false

bundle install
```

More information: https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails

Comment: `bundle config unset force_ruby_platform` worked for me! Mac OSX, latest version, latest ruby, rails everything. This did the trick. Thank you!